# Cannot reach files inside the root directory of my Android app

Tags: java, android

I have the code bellow:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/data/data/com.example.stavr.mydiary";
File file=new File(path);
File[] files = file.listFiles();
String arr[]=file.list();
List l=new ArrayList<>();
for(String i:arr){
    if(i.endsWith(". txt")){
        l.add(i);
    }
}
```

which returns 0 files on my array (NullPointerException to be exact), Iknow that there are files in that directory. If i change the directory to just

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

the code work and it returns all the files. I thing that i have done something wrong with the permissions. Could you please help me,
Thank you very much in advance..!!!

Comment: You should add file.exists() to your code and files==null check. And return if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to access your internal app data folder, you can do that by using a context object:
`String dir = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`

If you still want to access external storage then you should make sureyou have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: No. Not getFilesDir() but getExternalFilesDir(). No permission needed.

Comment: Yes I want to  access my internal app data folder. What should i use as "context" (sorry for the questions but I am new to android). I have the code above inside the "onCreate" method, if that helps...

Comment: Your Activity is a Context object, so just use `this` in `onCreate()`